# LINQ: Select values from two columns based on one of the column value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select, many-to-many

I have a table like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | Apple |
| Peter | Orange |
| Peter | Melon |
| John | Apple |
| John | Potato |
| John | Melon |
| Suzane | Kiwi |
| Suzane | Cucumber |
| Suzane | Orange |

I need to select values from **Column A** and values from **Column B** where **Column B** contains value **Orange**, so the resulting table should look like:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | Apple |
| Peter | Orange |
| Peter | Melon |
| Suzane | Kiwi |
| Suzane | Cucumber |
| Suzane | Orange |

Is this possible preferably in LINQ or Entity Framework please?

I've tried to find similar question, but have not succeeded so far

Comment: At least show your attempt so we can know what's not working. Thanks.

Comment: I have no clue how to approach this. I need to extend this query in such a way, that I get ALL the relevant Column A and Column B values if Column B contains Orange: var getAllValuesFromAandB = (from ab in db.Table where ab.ColumnB ==  'Orange' select new { ab.ColumnA, ab.ColumnB});

Comment: if you using DataTable: you will need to use asEnumerable for linq: var res = tableA.AsEnumerable().Where(w=> w.Field<string>("ColumnB").Contains("Orange")).ToList(); --> result would be list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by selecting all values of ColumnA where ColumnB matches Orange, e.g.

`var as = (from ab in db.Table where ab.ColumnB == 'Orange' select ab.ColumnA);`

Then select all records where column A has a value in that "list", e.g.

`var results = (from ab in db.Table where as.Contains(ab.A) select ab).ToList();`

Doesn't really matter that there are two queries as Linq2Sql or EF should combine them into one Sql query.

Comment: Many thanks sgmoore, works great. Before I would loop a dictionary, but lately, with rows reaching almost 1mil, it took cca 60 sec. With your solution it takes under 5 seconds!